# Why does my browser ask me to confirm full screen?

Tags: security, browser

I noticed that when I try to view a video or pdf file online in full screen, the browser ask me to confirm that I chose *full screen*. 
At least I saw this on `chrome`.

Is there a security issue associated with this or it is simply a double check?

Comment: I'm assuming it's to prevent abuse of the full screen feature by sites that wish to prey on inexperienced users (such as those who may not know how to come out of full screen mode) and show ads or do something malicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because going full screen without asking would confuse/annoy the user and could possibly be used to fake a windows desktop or password prompt to collect passwords. Also because switching to fullscreen can sometimes crash graphics cards. Pick a reason - they're all good.